# Adding mustache template variables while editing in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, mustache, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I'd like to use the TinyMCE editor to write text that includes Mustache template variables, specifically to include repeating groups.  I'm willing to use the html code view within TinyMCE if I have to (this is definitely a rarer use case).

I can do it just fine with an ordered list.  That is, in the code view I can write

```
<p>Blah blah blah</p>
<ol>
{{#info.courses}}
<li>{{course}} -- {{course_title}}</li>
{{/info.courses}}
</ol>
<p>All done!</p>
```

and I get a nice ordered list of all the courses and titles.

However, if I try the same thing with a table (replace `<ol>` with `<table>`,  etc) TinyMCE rearranges the code when I exit the HTML code view.  It removes the repetition tags and places both in a paragraph before the table.

Any way to get TinyMCE to leave my changes to the HTML alone?

I realize it is asking a lot to change the representation of what TinyMCE is working on, but thought I'd ask.

Alternatively, any suggestions on other approaches to include Mustache tags in the contents of the editor?

I'm currently using version 4.9.4.